# JBoss AS 7.1.1 deployment issue

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

I installed JBoss AS 7.1.1 server. 
I created my project war file and put it under  `[JBOSS_HOME]\standalone\deployments` folder.

My application is Spring MVC and here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>My WebApp</display-name>

    <!-- Configurations for the root application context (parent context) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jdbc.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/myapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>400</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

myapp-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.mvc" />

<bean id="PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>       


<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- the maximum file size in bytes = 10MB -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485760" />
</bean>
```

In the console log myapp-servlet.xml gets loaded by spring and all the request mapping are done from my controller. 
Partial Log output:

```
12:27:13,440 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-4) Mapped URL path [/myapp/welcome] onto handler 'myappController'
12:27:13,442 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-4) Mapped URL path [/myapp/welcome.*] onto handler 'myappController'
12:27:13,444 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-4) Mapped URL path [/myapp/welcome/] onto handler 'myappController'
12:27:13,527 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) FrameworkServlet 'myapp': initialization completed in 1028 ms
12:27:13,557 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myapp
12:27:13,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

My Controller class is simple:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myapp")
public class MyappController {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyappController.class);

    // @formatter:off
    /**
     * Welcome to MyApp
     * 
     * 
     * @return welcome.jsp Page
     * 
     * 
     */
    // @formatter:on
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome() {
        log.debug("welcome() called...");
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

If I access `http://localhost:8080/` then my welcome.jsp loads in webpage.

But the problem is
Now when I try to access using the following url `http://localhost:8080/myapp/welcome.jsp` I see this error in webpage:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myapp/welcome.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /myapp/welcome.jsp

description The requested resource (/myapp/welcome.jsp) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Console log:

```
11:46:05,871 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp' processing GET request for [/myapp/welcome]
11:46:05,873 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Looking up handler method for path /welcome
11:46:05,875 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Did not find handler method for [/welcome]
11:46:05,876 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp'
11:46:05,878 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Successfully completed request
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: what is in your /WEB-INF/spring/myapp-servlet.xml?

Comment: @eis I have edited my question and added myapp-servlet.xml content

Answer (score 0):

You should access your app with `http://localhost:8080/myapp/welcome` in your current configuration. You have placed your jsp files inside WEB-INF, which means they're not directly accessible, which is the standard practice in spring framework (and reasonable default otherwise as well.)

If you want to access welcome.jsp directly, you'll need to move it outside WEB-INF. I would not do that however, requests should always go through servlets and not point directly at .jsps.

Comment: I got your point, but it doesn't work. I tried that too. I added <mvc:annotation-driven/> too. I am sure there is a silly mistake. Just don't know where.

Comment: @Sujoy could you put your application to a github repo, for example, from where it can be tested?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But I can't put that to git as we can't use that from office. I have edited my question with console log. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sujoy here's a simplest possible, working, Spring-MVC app. Maybe you could use that and build on that: https://github.com/eis/spring-mvc-example

Comment: I could resolve the problem by using the following  `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`   But my question is why can't I have a mapping as /myapp? /myapp and /myapp/* both didn't work.

Comment: @Sujoy you can, but then you should use `/` in the controller requestmapping. you shouldn't have both.